# Problem with releasing new version of android app apk file

Tags: android, google-play-console

I am trying to release a new version of my android app in google play console. Howver, it shows the following errors while uploading in google play console.  Can anyone please help where is the problem?

Thanks in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzDts.png)

In the AndroidMenifest.xml file, it shows the following error. and I added android:exported="true" in the text, but did not work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywXOw.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nrg5B.png)

Comment: Should upload Signed build with same certificate which you have used for previous version.

Comment: how do I know which certificate I used for previous version?

Answer (score 0):

Make you `SplashActivity` android:exported="true", and all others to `false` as follow:

```
<activity android:exported="false" android:name=".ContactActivity" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however it seems not to work.

Comment: Can you show your target Sdk and compile sdk?